# Fire location event for test purpose

Tags: android, geolocation, titanium

I have testing geolocation function for Android.

I need to work away a few meters to fire this event.

(In the other hand, On iOS this function is fired when I launch application,
my iphone is 4G , but android uses Wifi, it might be the reason.)

Is there any good method to fire this function for testing purpose??

```
Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', function(e) {
   if (e.error) {       
        } else {
            Ti.API.info(e.coords);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In you I would do something like this:

```
var locationListener = function(e) {
   if (e.error) {       
        } else {
            Ti.API.info(e.coords);
    }
};
Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', locationListener); 
Ti.App.addEventListener('testLocation', locationListener);
```

And I would fire the testLocation when it's better for you with:

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('testLocation', {success: true, coords: {latitude: 0, longitude: 0}});
```

Obviously set the parameter with all the properties you need (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/LocationCoordinates) and don't forget to remove the testLocation event listener from Ti.App.

Answer (score 0):

before addEventListener setup the Ti.geolocation.Android

```
    Ti.Geolocation.Android.manualMode = true;
    Ti.Geolocation.Android.addLocationProvider(Ti.Geolocation.Android.createLocationProvider({
        name : Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS,
        minUpdateDistance : 1, // 1 metre 
        minUpdateTime: 1 // one per second
    }));
    Ti.Geolocation.Android.addLocationRule(Ti.Geolocation.Android.createLocationRule({
        provider : Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS,
        accuracy : 50, // Updates should be accurate to 50m
        maxAge: 1000, // Updates should be no older than 1 seconde 
        minAge: 200, // But  no more frequent than 5 per seconds
    }));
```